# Windows FTP Connection says Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, windows, iis, ftp

I've enabled windows ftp in IIS 7 and able to connect through `ftp://user:password@RBDRMSNMVM01`. However I tried the same through below C# snipet but I could not able to transfer the file.
It was failed at GetRequestStream() method call, which was saying "Unable to connect to the remote server"

```
strUserName = FTP Windows Server login user id
strPwd      = FTP Windows Server login password

FtpWebRequest request = null;
FileStream fs = null;
Stream reqStream = null;

request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(strFTPConnString);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUserName, strPwd);

reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
reqStream.Close();

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check whether strFTPConnString has the correct server address.

Also check if ports are being blocked by firewall.

Comment: You are right, the problem is with the IP Address. I've used the virtual ip address, rather than valid ip. It's working after changed to Original IP.